# Make Google Tag Manager (GTM) pageview wait for spa url title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I have a React SPA that handles all the url's titles on the frontend, so the `historyChange` event regsitered on GTM is getting all the visited urls with their titles right.

However, on first load of the SPA, let's say, reload with F5, you can see how it takes some time until our code on the frontend is able to set the correct title. It looks like by that time, the pageview or the historyChange event has already been registered.

Here you can see how we load our `GTM script`, which loads `analytics.js` automatically because we have it linked from the GTM dashboard.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WNJK84D"></script
```

Is there any way to wait for the title and avoid these incorrect data being registered?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

In your GTM config, you need to get rid of the "All Pages" trigger for the GA tag (that loads analytics.js).

Then you'll want to replace that with a custom data layer event that your SPA will push to the datalayer e.g. datalayer.push({event:'my-app-load'}) then trigger your GA tag off of this new trigger.

Comment: But your solution would only affect the load pageview, right? I mean, I would still like to keep all the history change tracking on my spa.

Comment: Sure, you can have to separate triggers and add them to the same GA tag. One with this custom event, the other that's based on history.